# Implementing multiple users within Identity and Access Bounded Context in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, php, domain-driven-design

I am developing a multi-tenant JobBoard Application using DDD approach. I have read to a great extent both the blue and red books. I have also read many articles on DDD online. However, I have not seen any easy-to-comprehend example on the implementation of the Identity and Access bounded context in this regard.

My application structure looks like this:

A tenant creates a JobBoard. A job board (which belongs to a tenant) has two users: Employer and Job Seeker.

I have two bounded context namely: Identity and JobBoard.

My question is what would be the best way to implement the Employer and JobSeeker User?

1. Should I have both the Employer and JobSeeker as entities (Aggregates) within the Identity bounded context or
2. Should I have a User Entity (Aggregate) within the Identity Bounded context and have both Employer and JobSeeker as Role types of a Role Value Object which will be an attribute of the User Class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Employer and JobSeeker don't authenticate in the same way, or you have security restrictions that require the two to be separated, I would have a single User object.

As an aside, it is not necessarily worthwhile to implement your own Identity subdomain, or at least to do so with a full fledged DDD model - aggregates, entities, etc.

Comment: Just to give more information on it. Employer and JobSeeker don't authenticate the same way. They are separate concerns with their own different portals. On the implementation of the identity domain, how do you handle identity and access without having a separate sub-domain for it?

Comment: You don't, but you just buy an off the shelf solution instead of implementing it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I would choose no. 2

`Employer` and `JobSeeker` seem to have a meaning only in the `JobBoard Bounded Context` so you should implement them as value objects in that BC, created based on the `Role` from `Identity Bounded Context`.